# T-SQL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP behaviour

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, casting

I have:

```
select convert(int, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 121)  AS shipmentCode
```

With this I pretend to give a unique code to a shipment of products that also has some information in it (meaning that I can convert the code back to time and have the shipment's full date/hour)

But I expect the int in shipmentCode to change every time I execute the procedure and it does not.

But if I do:

```
 select convert(varchar(255), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 121)  AS shipmentCode
```

The varchar changes with the time. As I need the code to be a number:

Can someone please, explain why this happens?

Any alternatives to achieve what I need?

Comment: As I am learning the reason why some of you are voting down this post is very important to me, so please, explain why you are doing so.

Comment: What if two shipments have an activity done on it at the exact same time thus necessitating the same timestamp? Tehy wouldn't be unique in that case. Even though this would be a rare occurence, you could, if possible, assign a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` to them (thus making them truly unique) and store the timestamp in another column. This way, you will have your unique code as well as the timestamp. Ofcourse, this depends on whether you have control on defining table structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This : `SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND,'1990-1-1',GETDATE())`

Comment: This will not return a unique number for records inserted within the same second.

Answer (score 2):

You are assuming that the value in `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is held as an `int` value.  If you actually start with a more precise datatype you will see the differences:

```
select convert(int, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 121)  AS shipmentCode
```

Returns: 42698

```
select convert(varchar(255), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 121)  AS shipmentCode
```

Returns: 2016-11-25 12:46:58.877

```
select convert(float, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 121)  AS shipmentCode
```

Returns: **42697.5326258873**  -- Note the decimal precision here.

If you want to return a meaningful single number as your ID, I would recommend using `sysdatetime` (which returns a very precise `datetime2`) to whatever precision is required to create a unique record per row, which you can format in a number of ways, such as the rather cumbersome:

```
select replace(replace(replace(replace(convert(nvarchar(25),sysdatetime(),121),' ',''),':',''),'-',''),'.','')
```

Which returns: 201611251246588791305 in the format yyyyMMddhhmmssfffffff

Answer (score 1):

This is shorter and faster than a full date/time translation and doesn't need converting from a string:

select convert(float, current_timestamp, 121)*10000000000  AS shipmentCode